# Setting bash options in a compound command

Tags: bash, shopt

I have found that setting the `extglob` shell option only within a compound compound results in failure of subsequent extended globs. Are shell options required to be set outside of compound commands? I did not see an indication of such a requirement in the Bash man pages.

As an example, the following script works fine (prints `a.0  a.1`):

```
#!/bin/bash
touch a.0   a.1 \
      a.b.0 a.b.1
shopt -s extglob
ls "a."!(b*)
```

However, if the last two lines are executed as a compound command, the script fails with the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
`    ls "a."!(b*)'
```

This was tested using Bash versions from 4.2 to 4.4 and with a variety of [compound commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Compound-Commands.html):

(1) conditional -- `if`

```
#!/bin/bash
touch a.0   a.1 \
      a.b.0 a.b.1
if true; then
    shopt -s extglob
    ls "a."!(b*)
fi
```

(2) braces -- `{ }`

```
#!/bin/bash
touch a.0   a.1 \
      a.b.0 a.b.1
{
    shopt -s extglob
    ls "a."!(b*)
}
```

(3) subshell -- `( )`:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch a.0   a.1 \
      a.b.0 a.b.1
(
    shopt -s extglob
    ls "a."!(b*)
)
```

In all cases, if the `shopt` is moved outside the compound command, the script succeeds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No part of a compound command executes before the entire command is parsed, which is obliquely documented in the [Shell Operation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation) section of the manual: all tokenising and parsing happens before "the" command executes. Enabling `extglob` changes the language syntax by adding new pattern-matching operators, which are recognised during tokenisation.

Because the `shopt` command hasn't executed at the time `!(` is reached, it's seen as either an attempted history expansion (`!`) or the control operator `(`, rather than `!(` being seen as a single item (and the same for `@(`, etc, except that there's no history expansion there).

When parsing reaches that token either case will generally be an error, though `!(...)` at the start of a line or after `time` is a negated subshell pipeline. "`` unexpected token `(' ``" means it couldn't accept a subshell expression in that spot.

This is somewhat annoying when you want extglob enabled only temporarily in a subshell. One workaround is to define a function that uses the glob you want, then re-disable extglob, and *then* call the function from the subshell with extglob enabled:

```
shopt -s extglob
f() { ls "a."!(b*) ; }
shopt -u extglob
(
    shopt -s extglob
    f
)
```

It's very clunky.

---

The same effect happens if you create an alias within a compound command, because they are also processed before parsing:

```
if true
then
    alias foo=echo
    foo bar
fi
foo xyz
```

will print `foo: command not found`, and then `xyz`, because the alias *is* created, but not available until the `if` is done.

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't realize that compound commands were parsed as a unit before execution. The behavior now makes sense.

Comment: @user001 I wouldn't be so charitable to say that it makes sense. Switching the lexer's mode *while in parsing* is nothing unheard of, and other languages like `C` or `perl` are able to do it fine. Notice that not being part of a compound command isn't enough, `shopt -s extglob` also has to be on a separate line. See also the discussion and examples [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521287/file-globbing-pattern-example-behaves-differently-in-bash-script-than-it-d/521289#comment964577_521289)

Comment: @mosvy: I meant that the observed behavior makes sense once one realizes that bash parses a compound command as a unit (not that the limitations of the parser are necessarily reasonable). Thanks for linking to the discussion in the other post.