# linux shell script with if and shopt

Tags: bash, syntax

I've written the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
#delete downloaded file

if [ "$param" == "delete" ]; then

    shopt -s extglob
    cd $DataPersistent/download/
    rm -f !($label.*)
    cd $DataPersistent/swm/install_pkg/
    rm -rf !($label|$label.json|active.json)
    shopt -u extglob
fi
...
```

When I remove the `if` statement, it works fine, but when I add the `if` statement, it results in the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/clear.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/bin/clear.sh: line 17: `    rm -f !($label.*)'
```

What's causing this? How can I fix it?

Comment: It does not have to do with if statements being removed. The round brackets () in bash create a subshell and that's what you are hitting. So `eval rm -rf '!("$label"|"$label".json|active.json)'` will do the trick. Single quote the expression

Answer (score 2):

`shopt -s extglob` changes the syntax of the shell.  Without this statement, the extended globbing pattern `!($label|$label.json|active.json)` is invalid syntax.

The issue is that before the shell executes the `shopt` command enabling the `extglob` shell option, *the whole `if` statement* is already parsed, and the syntax error found.

When the line that require the change in allowed syntax is not part of a compound command (which is what the `if` statement is), the `shopt` command has already enabled `extglob`, which is why it works.

To solve this, enable `extglob` before the `if` statement, and disable it afterwards.

This is the same issue as also found here: [Setting bash options in a compound command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522511/setting-bash-options-in-a-compound-command)

Comment: Thanks for your explain, it works now.